# Studying the convergence of $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2in}}{n\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Study the convergence of the following series:$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2in}}{n\sqrt{n}}$$

I thought of applying the root test:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}({\frac{e^{2in}}{n\sqrt{n}}})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{2i}}{n^{\frac{3}{2n}}}=e^i$

However is $e^i>1$?

**Questions**:

**1)** Is the application of the root test right? What conclusion can I take?

**2)** Which would be other alternative ways of solving the question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No! Root test doesn't apply. The way to do it is taking  absolute values and noting that $|e^{2in}|=1$

Comment: Also that is not the correct way to use the root test. The quantity for used in testing is $\vert a_n \vert ^{1/n}$, so actually the limit is just $1$, since $\vert \mathrm e ^{\mathrm i 2n} \vert = 1$.

Comment: @Conrad The root test DOES apply, but is inconclusive.

Comment: ???? If it's inconclusive how does it apply? Maybe it's a matter of semantics but if a method doesn't solve a problem, it doesn't really apply the way I see it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you apply the root test to a series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, what you should compute is the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert}$. That is *not* what you did.

On the other hand, $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left\lvert\dfrac{e^{2in}}{n\sqrt n}\right\rvert=\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}$. Since the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}$ converges (by the integral test), your series converges absolutely. In particular, it converges.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, if you know that $\sum \frac{1}{n^c}$ converges for $c>1$, and that $e^{2in} = \cos(2n) + i\sin(2n)$ then this isn't too hard.

Consider the series $$\sum |\frac{\cos(2n)}{n√n}| < \sum \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}},$$ and from here, we may conclude the original series converges.

EDIT: additionally, to answer your question about $e^{i} > 1$: this isn't true, but it contrarily, is not true that $e^{i}<1$. $e^{i} = \cos(1) + i\sin(1)$, and you are trying to compare this to a strictly real number. It is tantamount to asking if $i$ is greater than $1$. There's no total ordering on the complex numbers, so these kinds of comparisons don't make sense. Instead, you could consider $|e^{i}|$ which is, in fact, equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Application of the [ROOT TEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Test) shows

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{e^{i2n}}{n^{3/2}}\right|}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^{-3/2}}=1$$

So, the root test is inconclusive.

On the other hand, [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Test) is applicable since $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ monotonically decreases to $0$ and for all $N$, $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N e^{i2n} \right|$ is bounded (in fact it is bounded by $\csc(1)$).

The power of Dirichlet's test is not of full display here since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2n}}{n^{3/2}}$ converges absolutely.  But note that Dirichlet's test guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2n}}{n^a}$ converges for all $a>0$!

Comment: @pedrogomes Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.